# Fan not working on Thinkpad T440s (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: thinkpad, fan

When I run the 'sensors' command in terminal, I get this:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +55.0°C  (crit = +200.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +74.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
```

My /etc/thinkfan.conf settings are the following

```
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp3_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp2_input

(0,     0,      55)
(1,     48,     60)
(2,     50,     61)
(3,     52,     63)
(4,     56,     65)
(5,     59,     66)
(7,     63,     32767)
```

My settings in /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf are the following:

```
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

Shouldn't that mean that the fan should turn on at 55 degrees?

I have also tried running the following in terminal.

```
# echo level 7 > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

One tutorial suggested that this would turn on the fan automatically, but nothing happened for me.

Are there any other settings that I should configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved it for me was to, in BIOS, change the Thermal Management setting from Optimal Performance to Balanced.

Comment: Thanks. This enables the fan but the problem is not really solved as now the CPU is throttled more. This seems to be a linux specific problem as on windows the fan also works in "Optimal Performance" mode.